# Bullet point in iTunes Description

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, app-store-connect

Simple question. How to add a bullet-point (or) star icon in the iTunes description?  I can see a few apps are still able to do this.

(I tried inserting the unicode values in text - U+000A, but they are not getting rendered at all).

[image]

Comment: The Unicode character `U+000A` is a linefeed, not a bullet.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like an on-topic programming question.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For macOS: <kbd>Option (alt)</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>

For Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> **OR** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0149</kbd> (on the numpad)

Or just copy this :  `•`

Comment: Thank you. That was simple.

Comment: Very simple answer. Thanks @emotality

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the character palette which gives you access to all of the symbol and emoji characters. You can add a shortcut to the palette in your menu bar via system preferences. See also this [apple guide](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201586).